# JMeter not adding the soap header or keystore

Tags: java, soap, jmeter, soap-client, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMeter 3.1 version, I have created "Test Plan" and created a "Thread Group" then add the HTTP Request then add the "Keystore Configuration", "SOAP Message Signer" and "HTTP Header Manager". But still am request was not signed. Am getting an 
`Response code: 500 Response message: Internal Server Error`.

Also, I have tried to create SOAP/XML-RPC Request Test plan, getting same error in this way as well.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Bharathi

[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you please share your test plan snapshot? Thanks!

Comment: @NaveenKumar Namachivayam - Added the Test Plan Snap in Question section.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam - Can you able to help to resolve my issue?

Comment: Can you open JMeter behind proxy and try? Thanks!

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam - Getting "2017/05/11 12:01:46 ERROR - nz.co.breakpoint.jmeter.modifiers.SamplerPayloadAccessor: Raw post body required." error while running behind proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `SOAP Message Signer` is, but in order to encrypt an outgoing SOAP message in JMeter you need to follow the next steps:

1. In *system.properties* file (lives in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) configure your certificate like:

   ```
   javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
   javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/certificate.p12
   javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_certificate_password_here
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up

Also make sure your HTTP Header Manager is configured to send [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) with the value of `application/soap+xml` or whatever is required by your web service provider.

References:

- [Building a WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html)
- [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

Comment: I have updated the system.properties, still am having an issue in reading header.

`WARN o.a.j.c.KeystoreConfig: https.use.cached.ssl.context property must be set to false to ensure Multiple Certificates are used
INFO o.a.j.c.KeystoreConfig: Configuring Keystore with (preload: 'True', startIndex: 0, endIndex: 0, clientCertAliasVarName: 'portal3signkeys')
INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location: C:/KeyStore/KStore type JKS
INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Total of 1 aliases loaded OK from keystore`

Now getting Internal Error 500.

Comment: `ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: readResponse: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://bitlb02...
ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: Cause: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://bitlb02...
2017-05-10 12:04:09,476 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: Error Response Code: 500`

Comment: Http status code 500 stands for "Internal server error", check your server logs for the failure reason

Comment: Same URL was working fine in SOAPUI. If I have copied the latest sign request form SOAP to JMeter then it was working fine for 5 mins, after that signature gets expire, then am receiving this Internal Error. We need to set some other things for header sign?

Comment: Dmitri T - `SOAP Message Signer`, its new plugin available for 3.x JMeter version. For More Info - https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for heads up, I will check it on next available opportunity, previously I used to do some scripting in order to test secure/signed web services: [Take the Pain out of Load Testing Secure Web Services](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/take-pain-out-load-testing-secure-web-services)

Comment: Can you help me resolve my error. I am not getting response when I making a soap call from JMeter, As I said above I have done with all required setting but still it was showing internal error 500.

Comment: I simply cannot without knowing what algorithm is being used for message signing and the message format your web service expects.

Comment: Dmitri T - I have added images in Original Question, please go check. I am sending request to via HTTP Request and using 'SOAP Message Signer' to config keystores and also update system.properties with keystore informations.